# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to construct 'AudioWorkletNode' [ReactJS]

Tags: reactjs

```
class InputWorkletNode extends window.AudioWorkletNode {
    constructor(context) {
        super(context, 'input-processor');
    }

    get recBuffers() {
        return ['test', 'test!'];
    } 
}
```

When the code is put into my reactjs project (initiated with create-react-app), it's giving me the following error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to construct
>   'AudioWorkletNode': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object
>   constructor cannot be called as a function.

Has anyone had the same issue before? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it without the 'window'?

Comment: Can you show a code where you use this class?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by putting the code into public folder and change it to

```
window.InputWorkletNode = class InputWorkletNode extends window.AudioWorkletNode {
   constructor(context) {
       super(context, 'input-processor');
   }    get recBuffers() {
       return ['test', 'test!'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option that had success for me was to change from es5 to es6.

```
"target": "es6"
```

in tsconfig.json